# Is there an equivalent to java .war files for NPM?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

Using gradle and java, I can build and publish (into a local repository) various versions. If a deployment has issues, I can reroll by deploying a prior version.

I can't find anything comparable for NPM applications, e.g. vue.

I foun `npm pack` which seems to build something that I can later install via  `npm install`.

But I could not find out I then "run" the application. Are the any good documentations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unline Jave Javascript doesn't compile into anything (because its interpreted). This means that all you need it the source code.

A basic node app source code will look something like this

```
main.js       # entrypoint
packege.json  # dependencies
src/          # application codebase
```

So if you like to create an artifact that can be deployed to a server you need only to download the dependencies (that's what the `npm install` is for) and that's it basically.

Now a `node_module` directory will be created

```
main.js       # entrypoint
packege.json  # dependencies
src/          # application codebase
node_module/  # dependencies codebase
```

You can run the application with `node run main.js`. But if you are creating an artifact you should bundle (zip) all the files and upload then to a file server (this will be the closest thing to .war in this flow)

You can now unzip and run the node application on a server that has NodeJS installed.